# How do I stop menus from being nested in a dropdown on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a theme called Esplande on a Wordpress install on my WIMP server. I have three Pages set up... an adult, a child, and a child of that child.

Here is a screenshot of the menu dropdown and what it looks like (Extras ***adult*** > Open Editions ***child*** > Belle in Blue Dress ***child/child***):

[image]

What I'd like to is have my theme only go as deep as the first child (Extras > Open Editions). I don't want a secondary (and third, forth...) child off to the side.

Looking in the header.php I can see this piece of PHP which just creates the menus off of an array.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary_nav' ) ); ?>
```

Anyone have any idea where I can change this in Wordpress? I am by no means an expert with it and just use the vanilla install with the installed Esplande theme on top. I'm not sure if manipulating the array directly is the correct way to change this.

Comment: go to your menus section on the main wordpress admin UI, and remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that's done in WPs backend / admin dashboard: Go to Design > Menus. There you'll see all entries of your menu (if you have more than one menu, you have to select the appropriate one first).

The menu entries are aligned below each other, sub menu entries are a little bit further right, sub-sub-menus even more right. You can simply drag that "Belle in Blue Dress" entry a little bit to the left with the mouse. This should move it into the regular submenu. (You'll have to save that first, though)

Comment: I see what was happening.... my theme was using a default method for displaying the menus. The Menu section was never set up by me. Now I see I can override it all in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using :

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary_nav', 'depth' => 2 ) );
?>
```

Just replace `2` with your desired depth. Note that `0` means all.

[For a full reference see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)